# Friction vs drag/resistance force

Tags: forces, friction, drag

we know that friction is a kind of resistance force, so friction should some how related to resistance force, but i just curious why they have different formula indeed.

The friction formula is given by $f=\mu N$, where $N$ is normal force, $\mu$ is friction coefficient.

While for drag/resistance force $F_R=-C_1v-C_2v^2$ where

$F_R=-C_1v$ at luminar flow,

$F_R=-C_1v-C_2v^2$ at intermediate flow

$F_R=-C_2v^2$ at turbulence flow

I just curious that since friction is a type of resistance force, then why it depend on normal force instead of velocity as in the formula of resistance force

Comment: You are referring to 2 kinds of resistive forces exerted by very different systems. The first force you describe seems to be the friction exerted at a solid-solid interface, while the second one is the drag of an object moving through a fluid. The two systems described by those equations are vastly different, and in fact not even described by the same areas of physics. Why do you expect them to yield the same formula or to behave in similar ways? For instance, how could you have a solid-solid force whose expression depends on the Reynolds number, when there isn't any flow in that case?

Comment: Although all of these are examples of resistive forces, the very fact that their force laws are so different warrants us to be careful in calling them different things! Despite widespread misuse, we should not call viscous force $F\propto v$ as friction $F\propto N$, nor mix up the linear viscosity with quadratic drag / resistance, and be as precise when talking about all these different resistances as we can.

Comment: Physicists in the UK who watched *University Challenge* (on, I believe, 6th November 2023) might have been distressed when 'friction' rather then 'resistive forces' was given by the question-master as the right answer to "What causes damping of simple harmonic motion?".

Comment: Wow, i think there might be a general expression to conclude and link all these resisitive force into one, but physicist still havent able to derive it

Comment: Concluding all force into 1 type as like the 4 main force (gravitational, electric, weak and magnetic)